# How to remove rows by condition

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements, subset

I'm trying to delete rows for which the condition is not satisfying
eg.Remove that Subject row which do not have all period's value
following is the dataframe

```
Subject          Period
1                  1
1                  2
1                  3
2                  1
2                  2
2                  3
3                  1
3                  2
4                  1
4                  2
4                  3


Subject          Period
1                  1
1                  2
1                  3
2                  1
2                  2
2                  3
4                  1
4                  2
4                  3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `dplyr` solution.

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% 
  group_by(Subject) %>%
  filter(all(unique(dat$Period) %in% Period)) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 9 x 2
#   Subject Period
#     <int>  <int>
# 1       1      1
# 2       1      2
# 3       1      3
# 4       2      1
# 5       2      2
# 6       2      3
# 7       4      1
# 8       4      2
# 9       4      3
```

A base R solution.

```
dat_list <- split(dat, f = dat$Subject) 
keep_vec <- sapply(dat_list, function(x) all(unique(dat$Period) %in% x$Period))
dat_keep <- dat_list[keep_vec]

dat2 <- do.call(rbind, dat_keep)
dat2
#      Subject Period
# 1.1        1      1
# 1.2        1      2
# 1.3        1      3
# 2.4        2      1
# 2.5        2      2
# 2.6        2      3
# 4.9        4      1
# 4.10       4      2
# 4.11       4      3
```

A solution using `purrr` and `dplyr`.

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  split(f = .$Subject) %>%
  keep(~all(unique(dat$Period) %in% .x$Period)) %>%
  bind_rows()
dat2
#   Subject Period
# 1       1      1
# 2       1      2
# 3       1      3
# 4       2      1
# 5       2      2
# 6       2      3
# 7       4      1
# 8       4      2
# 9       4      3
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "Subject          Period
1                  1
                  1                  2
                  1                  3
                  2                  1
                  2                  2
                  2                  3
                  3                  1
                  3                  2
                  4                  1
                  4                  2
                  4                  3",
                  header = TRUE)
```

Comment: this was just an example, subject row must be deleted based on condition eg. if either of three periods not there for a perticular subject, then that subject must be deleted

Answer (score 0):

Consider `ave` for inline aggregation then `subset` accordingly:

```
sub_df <- subset(df, ave(Period, Subject, FUN=max) != 3)
```

Comment: Seems lot of assumptions here. `Period` would always be numbered as 1, 2, 3...(what if they are A, B, C ? ) and the maximum number of periods would always be 3. (What if there are more than 3 unique periods? A, B, C, D, E ? )

Comment: Correct this is not generalizable but OP does not mention such precise specs but does comment on three periods with posted numbered data.